# Bison: $1 of `stmt' has no declared type

Tags: regex, bison

```
%{

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "mycalc.h"

extern int int_num;
extern char* yytext;

%}

%token TOK_NUM TOK_ID TOK_SEMICOLON TOK_VAR TOK_EQ TOK_PRINTLN TOK_LPARA TOK_RPARA TOK_ADD TOK_MUL

%union
{
  int int_val;
  char *id_val;
}

%type <id_val> expr TOK_ID 
%type <int_val> stmt TOK_NUM

%left TOK_LPARA TOK_RPARA
%left TOK_MUL
%left TOK_ADD

%%

prog:
    stmts {  startit();  }
;


stmts:

    | stmt TOK_SEMICOLON stmts
;



stmt:
      TOK_VAR TOK_ID    {  defvar(presentlevel,yylval.id_val,0);   }
    | TOK_ID TOK_EQ expr  {  assignvar(presentlevel,$1,$3);  }
    | TOK_PRINTLN TOK_ID {  printf("the value of id %d",$2); }
    | TOK_LPARA stmts TOK_RPARA {   if($1=="{") 
                        { 
                        presentlevel=presentlevel+1;
                        }

                       if($3=="}")
                    {
                       if(presentlevel>1)
                       {
                            presentlevel=presentlevel-1;
                       }
                        }  };

expr:
      TOK_NUM  {  $$=atoi($1);  }
    | TOK_ID  { myvar *h ;
            h=getvar(presentlevel,$1);
            $$=h->val;
          }
    | expr TOK_ADD expr {$$=$1+$2;}
    | expr TOK_MUL expr {$$=$1*$2;}
;

%%

int yyerror(char *s,int x)
{

printf("Syntax Error at %d",line_num);
return 0;

}

int main()
{

startit();

presentlevel=1;

yyparse();
return 0;

}
```

I have declared the types for the id_val and int_val below the union as you can see. Still it is causing an error. Here are the errors that I am getting.

```
calc.y:46.44-45: $1 of `stmt' has no declared type
calc.y:51.43-44: $3 of `stmt' has no declared type
calc.y:65.47-48: $2 of `expr' has no declared type
calc.y:66.47-48: $2 of `expr' has no declared type
make: *** [calc] Error 1
```

Can somebody tell us why is it showing the error inspite of declaring the type.

Comment: Please can somebody help me out here???

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error messages tell you pretty much exactly what is going on.  For the first one, line 46 is:

```
    | TOK_LPARA stmts TOK_RPARA {   if($1=="{")
```

this is a rule for `stmt`, and the error tells you that `$1` (which comes from `TOK_LPARA`) has no type.  You can see that from its delaration:

```
%left TOK_LPARA TOK_RPARA
```

If you want to be able to access a value from `TOK_LPARA` here, you need to give it a type, probably `<id_val>`.  Then you'll have the problem that `==` will compare pointers, not pointed at strings.  The other errors all indicate similar problems.

You also have problems with not setting `$$` in `stmt` actions (you've declared a type for `stmt`) causing them to have garbage values.